# When I am clicking my detail disclosure button then its crashed my app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I had created an app like remainder but whenever I clicked on detail disclosure to edit the name of existing list name then suddenly it crashes the app. I had written a code of accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath within my class. Below their is a code of my accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath method.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let navigationController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ListDetailViewController") as! UINavigationController

    let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! ListDetailViewController

    controller.delegate = self

    let checklist = dataModel.lists[indexPath.row]

    controller.checklistToEdit = checklist

    presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Show the crash informations.

Comment: please check "ListDetailViewController" is identifier for navigation controller or ListDetailViewController in storyboard

Comment: could not cast value of type 'to_do_list.AddItemViewController' to 'to_do_list.ListDetailViewController' @Jens

Comment: i think you are using wrong identifier "ListDetailViewController" for navigation controller. please check in storyboard once again

Comment: I had checked all the connections but its all cleared @moinuddin-girach

Comment: not connection i means to check identifier of navigation controller it might be different. reason behind that is you created on controller which identifier is "ListDetailViewController" and you are using same for navigation controller how it is possible ?

Comment: I had use AddChecklist identifier to add list and i had use EditChecklist identifier to edit the existing list name. But now i am getting an  thread sigabrt error

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because one of these variables are nil:

- storyboard
- navigationController.topViewController

or you are getting an `index out of bounds` error here

```
dataModel.lists[indexPath.row]
```

From your code it's also not obvious, if this line:

```
storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ListDetailViewController") as! UINavigationController
```

Really does what it should do, since your string shows, that you want a ListDetailViewController but you cast the result of the function to a `UINavigationViewController` which could also lead to the crash.

To fix the crash and understand what's going on rewrite the code like this (just for testing purporse since this code is ugly):

```
if let navigationController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ListDetailViewController") as! UINavigationController 
{
  if let controller = navigationController.topViewController as? ListDetailViewController
  {
    controller.delegate = self
    if dataModel.list.count < indexPath.row
    {
      let checklist = dataModel.lists[indexPath.row]
      controller.checklistToEdit = checklist
      presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
    } else 
    {
       println("array out of index")
    }
  } else 
  {
     println("topView Controller of navigation controller is nil")
  }
} else 
{
  println("navigationController or storyboard is nil")
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what that means

Comment: Should i give you the whole code of my app to understand

Comment: I don't understand the error message. I assume that you've provided the part where the app crashes. But without understanding the error/crash message, there isn't much i can do

Comment: In debug area it showing an error "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: where is it happening? are you using the code i provided in my answer?

Comment: share your project if possible in your question..:) @shahinaliagharia

Comment: should i get your email so i can directly send you

Comment: i've updated my code again. maybe you are getting an index out of bounds. try my new code please

Answer (score 0):

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
 {
     let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ListDetailViewController") as ListDetailViewController
     controller.delegate = self
     controller.checklistToEdit = dataModel.lists[indexPath.row]
     self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
```

Hope this will help you.